# Can't remove item from aux.Value on list of dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

Hey guys i can't remove posição ISBN position ISBN from the new `List<Criar_Requisitos>`. I have the `ISBN` on the Book List and saves on the new `List<Criar_Requisitos>`, im using `foreach` and `if`s. I keep having a error on the *second* in of `foreach`, can you guys help?

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<Criar_Requisitos>> aux in Nova_Lista)
{
    foreach (Criar_Requisitos posição in aux.Value)
    {
        if (Introduzir_ISBN == posição.ISBN)
        {
            aux.Value.Remove(posição);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to remove it oustside the foreach statement.

Comment: Thanks i fix the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [RemoveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netframework-4.8) instead of inner `foreach`:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<Criar_Requisitos>> aux in Nova_Lista) 
  aux.Value.RemoveAll(posição => posição.ISBN == Introduzir_ISBN);
```